# Android - Auto instrumental test on alpha version release

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have a problem every time I upload an alpha version for my application:

from nowhere - API requests from my app starts shooting like someone check all of my app.

the problem is, this case always delete some tables in my DB. (because I guess they click on my menu item which does this...)

Now for my assumption:

Google run some Auto tests on my app\api's.
If my assumption is right, How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature in Google Play called [pre-launch reports](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports). I'd recommend using them as they test your app on lots of devices, and can find crashes and bugs on devices or versions of Android you may not have thought of trying.

However, if you really want to disable pre-launch reports, the instructions are on [this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270).

> Pre-launch reports are automatically generated when you publish an app to the open, closed, or internal test track. To disable all pre-launch reports for your app:
>
> - Sign in to your Play Console.
> - Select an app.
> - Select Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings.
> - Next to "Enable pre-launch reports," move the switch to the left until it turns gray. If you want to turn pre-launch reports on again at a later time, move the switch back to the right until it turns blue.

Comment: Greate, as I suspect. thank you. this application is managment only for 4-5 alpha users. no need any tests...